# Why is Typescript asking to assign Getters?

Tags: angular, typescript

Typescript prompts: 'is missing the following properties from type Test: testGetter'.

```js
export interface ITest {
  id?: string | number;
  property: string;
}

export class Test implements ITest {
  id?: string | number;
  property: string;

  constructor(test?: Test) {
    Object.assign(this, test);
  }

  get testGetter() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because ```ITest``` requires testGetter. As far as you are implementing ```ITest``` you need to implement all properties and methods

Comment: ITest is an Interface, would that apply to Interfaces too?

Comment: Add you `ITest` interface here

Comment: Yes, interfaces force you to follow the contract. This is one of the main use of them.

Comment: Your code still have a problem with that interface? It should actually work

Comment: It's not working, its strange as I have done it before, first time with this issue.

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Comment: @AnthonyVasquez, your code doesn't give me any error from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface declares the property as a string. However, you don't initialize it in the class so it's real type is `string|undefined`

Might be you misspelled the interface?

Initialize it and code should works

```
export interface ITest {
  id?: string | number;
  property: string;
}

export class Test implements ITest {
  id?: string | number;
  property: string = '';

  constructor(test?: ITest) {
    Object.assign(this, test);
  }

  get testGetter() {
    return 1;
  }
}

new Test(new Test()) //compiles
new Test({ id: '1', property: '2' }) //compiles
```

Comment: hmm i dont think it's the problem.. the property's type is `string` as long as the type is defined. It will not judge its type automatically based on its current value.

Comment: This kinda "new" feature in TypeScript; Try to create new class ```class MyClass {name:string}``` and TypeScript will complain about ```Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.```

Comment: what is the typescript version?

Comment: Well, in my case is complaining when you try to assign the new Class, it's asking for the Getter assignation: in this case: testGetter.

Comment: @yash 3.9.2 however it was implemented earlier.

Comment: @AnthonyVasquez now I see, blind me!

Comment: hmm still, it doesnt give me any error. and what's wrong with `class MyClass {name:string}`? so any class without the properties initialization is error?

Comment: @yash check ```strictNullCheck``` flag in tsconfig

Comment: Ok, i dont have it set in my tsconfig. if it depends on the tsconfig :) hard to say which is better

Comment: I am thinking, might be OP misspelled the interface name? ``` constructor(test?: Test)``` =>   constructor(test?: ITest)

Comment: It's because OP had the class as the constructor argument not the parameter.  Plain object will not have `testGetter` so the complier complains.  Changing to the interface (which has not `testGetter` as a property) stops the error.